# Beamer - blank black frame

Tags: beamer

I'm making a presentation with LaTeX Beamer package. And I want to have a slide where the screen is all black so I can use other media. Is there a way to insert a black slide simply?

Comment: If you were using [Impressive](http://impressive.sourceforge.net/) to display your slides, it's as simple as pressing `B` at the right moment...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the background color of a frame in Beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8043/change-the-background-color-of-a-frame-in-beamer)

Comment: @Alan Munn changing the background colour won't change _all_ the frame to black. The structural elements will still be there.

Comment: @Seamus Other than the navigation symbols, changing the background canvas does exactly that. No other elements are visible. So Herbert's solution is an exact duplicate of the solutions posted in the question I reference.

Comment: @Alan No. The relevant difference is the `plain` option that turns off, say, the top bar and lower bar from the `infolines` outertheme.

Comment: Ah, yes, I still had `[plain]` in my test file.

Comment: @Alan and in fact, even if the _answers_ had been identical, I think the _questions_ are different enough that I don't think this should be closed...

Comment: @Seamus I just noticed it is the same with evince - my pdf viewer of choice.

Comment: “Blank black” is an oxymoron.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\frame{foo}

\bgroup
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\begin{frame}[plain]{}
\end{frame}
\egroup

\frame{bar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need `\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}` inside your group to make the slide totally blank.

Comment: I know, but it may still be useful to have the symbols

Answer (score 3):

If you have \mode* on then the background color remains set for subsequent slides even if you have the command wrapped in a group. This works:

```
\mode<presentation>{
  {   
    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
    \begin{frame}[plain]{}
    \end{frame}
  }
}
\mode<presentation>{\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}}
\mode*
```

Comment: I assume that's in the preamble, how exactly do you switch within your document from one slide to another?

Answer (score 0):

It might additionally be necessary to use `\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[default]` before `\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}`. Have a look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153582/beamer-strange-behavior-when-changing-background-color/153619#153619?newreg=d7334e8a4b1743198e376e6a9e7f9f61) post.