# Beamer: Strange behavior when changing background color

Tags: beamer, color

Using `\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}` works fine if I want to change the background color. However once I used `\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{}` it doesn't work anymore:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

% as expected

\begin{frame}{Test}
white
\end{frame}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\begin{frame}{Test}
\textcolor{white}{black}
\end{frame}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
\begin{frame}{Test}
white again
\end{frame}

% confusing

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\begin{frame}{Test}
should be black
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT: Why do I do this?**

I sometimes use a code like this

```
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{picture.jpg}}
```

to use a picture to fill the background. I clear the picture by using

```
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{}
```

How else could I clear the picture?

---

Ok:

[image]

Ok:

[image]

Ok:

[image]

Here's the mistake:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: AFAIK a Beamer template is some LaTeX code. The default template code for `background canvas` surely has `\usebeamercolor{background canvas}` or equivalent in it. So if you set the template to empty, the color will never get used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Andrew Swann's answer explains why this happens but I thought you might find it useful to see what you might want to do instead. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve by setting the template to empty but it may be that you really just wanted to eliminate the headline/footline etc. so that the entire area of the slide was available for content. I've therefore modified your example a little to show some of the possibilities:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

% as expected

\begin{frame}{Test}
white
\end{frame}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\begin{frame}{Test}
\textcolor{white}{black}
\end{frame}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
\begin{frame}{Test}
white again
\end{frame}

% confusing

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\begin{frame}[plain]{Test}
Perhaps you just wanted to use a \texttt{plain} frame rather than eliminating the background altogether.
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=red}
\begin{frame}{Test}
As others have explained, the template is now completely empty so the colour specification has no effect.
\end{frame}


\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[default] % <--- Important

\begin{frame}{Test}
Now the template is reset to default, the colour specification earlier changes the background to red.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I added information to the question why I used \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{}.

Comment: @ManuelKuehner Note that my code answers your edited question. Look at `\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[default]` before the last frame and notice that it restores the default template which means the colour specification affects the final frame, even though it did not affect the preceding one. (The last frame is red; the one before is white.)

Comment: Great! Thanks. I had this problem for literally years.

Answer (score 5):

The `beamer` template `background canvas` is the code for making the background.  By default it is

```
\defbeamertemplate*{background canvas}{default}
{%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{background canvas}{}{\color{bg}\vrule width\paperwidth height\paperheight}%
}
```

As you see it includes code that uses the key `bg`.  Your command

```
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{}
```

removes this code, and now the option `bg` is not used, so has no effect.

Comment: Thanks. I added information to the question why I used \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{}.

Comment: Is it important that it's the starred version?