# ignorenonframetext option breaks frame background color option?

Tags: beamer

I'm trying to change the background color of a frame in Beamer and have been following the example in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153582/beamer-strange-behavior-when-changing-background-color).  The example version works fine, but if you introduce the `ignorenonframetext` argument to the `\documentclass` declaration, all of the frames get a white background.

This changes the background color, but produces a frame with the non-frame text.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

Some non-frame text.

\begin{frame}{Test}
white
\end{frame}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\begin{frame}{Test}
\textcolor{white}{black}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And this hides the non-frame text but doesn't change the background color.  The only difference is the first line.

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}

\begin{document}

Some non-frame text.

\begin{frame}{Test}
white
\end{frame}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\begin{frame}{Test}
\textcolor{white}{black}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Is this a bug?  What's going on here?

**EDIT**

It just occurred to me that this isn't a bug: of course it's ignoring the background color command, it's nonframe text.  In which case the question is how to set the background color with the `ignorenonframetext` option in place?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out.  There may be a more elegant way to do this but the following works.

The trick is to temporarily disable `ignorenonframetext` and re-enable it after the frame in question with `\mode*`:

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}

\begin{document}

Some non-frame text.

\begin{frame}{Test}
white
\end{frame}

% Turn off ignorenonframetext and change the color
\mode<all>
{\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\begin{frame}{Test}
\textcolor{white}{black}
\end{frame}
}
\mode*
% Return to ignorenonframetext

% Revert the background color to the default for the next frame
\mode<all>
{\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
\begin{frame}{Test\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=red}}
white again
\end{frame}
}
\mode*

\end{document}
```