# Defining Moleskine paper colour

Tags: color

I use Moleskine journals and I really like the colour of the paper. I find it quite good for the eyes compared to the pure white, nonetheless I have no idea how to reproduce this color in LaTeX.

An example of the paper can be found here:
[enter link description here](http://bit.ly/1x8RnVj)

I would be very grateful if someone could reproduce this color in TeX as well.

Comment: You can try with this: rgb(243, 229, 206).

Comment: @Aradnix thanks. I was able to define the color the way you suggested.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have the color then reproducing is not difficult with `xcolor` package. Here TikZ loads it anyways.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\definecolor{moleskin}{HTML}{FFF8DC}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip[preaction={fill=moleskin},rounded corners=.5cm] (-5,-3.5) rectangle (5,3.5);
\draw[style=help lines] (-5,-3.5) grid[step=0.3] (5,3.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No moles were harmed in the making of this image. +1

Answer (score 5):

If you want to keep the original paper color white, while viewing it in 'moleskine', you can change the paper color (the background color) in some PDF viewers. For instance, in Okular v.0.19.3:

```
Settings -> Configure Okular... -> Accessibility -> Change colors -> Change Paper Color
```

This feature was just implemented in the Internal PDF Viewer of TeXstudio too, and will probably be available in the next stable version. Look [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/1299/).

What you see in your viewer (color #FDF6E3) / The real PDF (color #FFFFFF).

[image] [image]

The colors are quite similar, but you can use a tool like [Gpick](http://www.gpick.org/) to compare their hex triplets.

If you really want to change the paper color in LaTeX, e.g., when working in drafts, but want to go back to white for the final version:

```
\documentclass{article}% option [final] disables the creme background.
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ifdraft}
\ifoptionfinal{}{\pagecolor[HTML]{FDF6E3}}
\begin{document}
example
\end{document}
```

Concerning the color, maybe you would be interested in the [Solarized color palette](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized). This 'moleskine' color seems quite similar to the color Solarized base3 (#FDF6E3, the color I used in the left-hand side figure).

P.S.: I wrote a very similar answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/390623/23481