# Beamer: background color for section page?

Tags: beamer, backgrounds, presentations

I have defined a beamer template for a section page:

```
\setbeamertemplate{section page}
{

  \begin{centering} 
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{section title} 
  \usebeamerfont{section title} 
   \insertsection
  \par 
  \end{centering}   
}
```

which I make appear at the beginning of each section:

```
\AtBeginSection{\frame{\sectionpage}}
```

Given that the [background canvas of a frame has to be set before beginning the frame](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8043/change-the-background-color-of-a-frame-in-beamer), is there any way to extend the template to include a background color for section pages?

What I'm doing right now is for every section:

```
\begingroup
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=mySectionBackgroundColor}
\section{Content}
\endgroup
```

But I would like to just do:

```
\section{Content}
```

and have the background color set as part of the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the background color *inside* the `\AtBeginSection`:

```
\AtBeginSection{
\begingroup
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=blue}
\frame{\sectionpage}
\endgroup
}
```

Then

```
\section{Content}
```

should give you a blue page.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively we could create the actual `\frame` inside the template:

```
\setbeamertemplate{section page}
{
    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=blue}
    \frame{
      \begin{centering} 
      \usebeamercolor[fg]{section title} 
      \usebeamerfont{section title} 
       \insertsection
      \par 
      \end{centering}   
    }
}
```

making the "grouping" obsolete:

```
\AtBeginSection{\sectionpage}
```

Additionally we can now create an `\usebackgroundtemplate` for *section pages*.