# Beamer template with different style options for frames

Tags: beamer, header-footer, templates, optional-arguments

I am working on a beamer template which tries to mimick an existing .ppt-template from my institute. My problem now is, that the beamer template should be able to have frames with different styles for the headline within a single presentation. (do not ask why this would be necessary, I do not know)

After having a look into `beamerbaseframe.sty` and playing a bit with frame options, I came up with the following code

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{mytheme}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        left
    \end{frame} 

    \begin{frame}[rightslide]
        right
    \end{frame} 

    \begin{frame}
        should be left again :(
    \end{frame}     

\end{document}
```

using `beamerthememytheme.sty`

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \rule{.5\paperwidth}{14mm}
}

\define@key{beamerframe}{rightslide}[true]{%
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{\hfill\rule{.5\paperwidth}{14mm}}%
}
```

So the **question** is now: how can I revert to the default headline after the slide with the option `rightslide`?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can define two different templates and reset the headline to the default style before a new frame starts.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\defbeamertemplate{headline}{mydefault}{%
  \rule{.5\paperwidth}{14mm}%
}
\defbeamertemplate{headline}{rightslide}{%
  \emph{\hfill\rule{.5\paperwidth}{14mm}}%
}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{%
  \setbeamertemplate{headline}[mydefault]%
}

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{rightslide}[true]{%
  \setbeamertemplate{headline}[rightslide]%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  left
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}[rightslide]
  right
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  is left again
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I made use of your code in my answer here (last one added), so thanks! https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8043

Answer (score 0):

Using a similar approach as the moloch beamer theme for its [standout frame](https://github.com/jolars/moloch/blob/main/src/beamerinnerthememoloch.dtx#L435-L472), one could use a group to restrict the changes to just this one frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \rule{.5\paperwidth}{14mm}
}

\providebool{rightslide}
\define@key{beamerframe}{rightslide}[true]{%
    \booltrue{rightslide}
    \begingroup
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{\hfill\rule{.5\paperwidth}{14mm}}%
}
\pretocmd{\beamer@reseteecodes}{%
  \ifbool{rightslide}{
    \endgroup
    \boolfalse{rightslide}
  }{}
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        left
    \end{frame} 

    \begin{frame}[rightslide]
        right
    \end{frame} 

    \begin{frame}
        is left again :)
    \end{frame}     

\end{document}
```

[image]