# Passing arguments to custom frame option

Tags: beamer, templates, optional-arguments

Follow up to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/174213/36296

Long story short: I wondered how to pass arguments to custom frame options. For example add customisable an image to the frametitle.

---

And on special request from Leon Meier a MWE (I wonder how samcarter could answer this question without it):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\defbeamertemplate{frametitle}{mydefault}{%
  \insertframetitle%
}

\defbeamertemplate{frametitle}{imagetitle}{%
  \insertframetitle \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{example-image}%
}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{%
  \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[mydefault]%
}

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{imagetitle}[true]{%
  \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[imagetitle]%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{bla}
  left
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}[imagetitle]
    \frametitle{bla}
  right
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{bla}
  is left again
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @LeonMeier Can be found in my self answer I posted together with this questions to share this information with the nice people from this community.

Comment: @LeonMeier Specially for you I added one :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\defbeamertemplate{frametitle}{mydefault}{%
  \insertframetitle%
}

\defbeamertemplate{frametitle}{imagetitle}[1]{%
  \insertframetitle \includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{#1}%
}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{%
  \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[mydefault]%
}

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{imagetitle}[true]{%
  \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[imagetitle]{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{bla}
  left
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}[imagetitle=example-grid-100x100bp.pdf]
    \frametitle{bla}
  right
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{bla}
  is left again
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]