# How can I control the \logo command to reposition the logo and make it appear only on the title slide?

Tags: beamer, templates

I am already using `\titlegraphic` for something else. I am making a general template so I cannot accept other hacks like slipping the logo into the author or title fields. I want to control `\logo` to

1. Set the position of the logo on the slide
2. Choose which slides the logo appears on

If this cannot be done, is it at least possible to turn off the default logo completely? I can then use `\insertlogo` in my template.

Every question about `\logo` is answered by someone suggesting using a different command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best workaround I found so far was to define my own command based on this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262420/120014

My solution:

In `beamerthemeNAME.sty`:

`\newcommand{\institutionlogo}[1]{\def\insertinstitutionlogo{#1}}`

In `main.tex`:

`\institutionlogo{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{logo_file_name}}`

In `beamerinnerthemeNAME.sty` (the last node uses `\insertinstitutionlogo`):

```
% Title page
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{NAME}[1][]
{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=\paperheight]{title page header}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0cm, 
block/.style={
  %draw,  % Uncomment this to see boxes around the areas (for debugging)
  text width=0.92*\paperwidth,
  anchor=north west,
  minimum height=1cm,
  }, 
font=\large
]%
  \useasboundingbox[](0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,\paperheight);
  % Title
  \node[block,white,align=left,anchor=west] at (0.5,\paperheight-0.5\barheight){\usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle};
  % Authors, institutions, and date
  \node[block,black,align=left,text width=0.435\paperwidth] at (0.5,\paperheight-\barheight-0.3cm){\usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor \\ {\vskip0.3cm \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute} \\ \vskip0.3cm \usebeamerfont{author}\insertdate};
  % Title graphic
  \node[block,black,text width=0.435\paperwidth,align=right,anchor=north east] at (\paperwidth-0.5cm,\paperheight-\barheight-0.3cm){\inserttitlegraphic};
  % Institutional logo
  \node[block,black,text width=0.435\paperwidth,align=right,anchor=south east] at (\paperwidth-0.15cm,0.15cm){\insertinstitutionlogo};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
```

Also thanks to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146682/120014, which is how I figured out how to do the initial setup of the `beamer*theme*.sty` files.

Comment: This works well enough that I don't need `\logo` for my specific case anymore, but I didn't learn how to control `\logo` itself.