# How to remove footer for specific type of slides/frames?

Tags: beamer, footer

I have the following MWE in which I am trying to remove footer only for slides of type standout. For all other type of slides I need the footer. However, with my MWE, I have to manually set footer on or off after each standout frame. How to set this globally such that footers are automatically removed for standout frames?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\title{The title of the paper}
\author{XYZ}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\begin{frame}[standout]
Welcome!
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{Methodology}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[standout]
Thank you!
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE**

Based on samcarter's suggestion. I was able to remove the footer for standout frames, but the frames after the first standout frame also disappears. I want the footer to be off only for standout frames.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
% \usepackage{etoolbox}

% \BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{%
%   \setbeamertemplate{footline}
% }

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{standout}[true]{%
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}%
}
\makeatother

\title{The title of the paper}
\author{XYZ}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

% \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\begin{frame}[standout]
Welcome!
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{Methodology}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[standout]
Thank you!
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/174213/36296

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
% \usepackage{etoolbox} % automatically loaded by recent versions of beamer

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{%
 \setbeamertemplate{footline}[split theme]
}

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{standout}[true]{%
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}%
}
\makeatother

\title{The title of the paper}
\author{XYZ}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[standout]
Welcome!
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{Methodology}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[standout]
Thank you!
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The answer works with the package `etoolbox` that is now commented in the anwer.

Comment: @nxkryptor etoolbox is automatically loaded by beamer for the last year or two. If this does not work for you, you should update your tex distribution