# Dedicated frametitle in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, frame-title

I'd like to create a key `strong` such that the title of a frame appears in orange on a gray background when I enter `\begin{frame}[strong]`.  The problem is that the change becomes global.  Is there a way to do so such that only frames with the `strong` key are modified?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{strong}[]{%
  \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=gray,fg=orange}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{My Normal Title}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[strong]
  \frametitle{My Strong Title}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{My Normal Title}

  This title should be normal
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: maybe this answer could help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/174213/36296

Comment: Thank you.  This is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @ user94293 me to :)