# Different frames in one beamer presentation

Tags: beamer

I need to prepare a beamer presentation in which I shall have multiple kinds of frames (Discussing frame, Formalizing frame, Problems Frame, etc.). They are simple  frames, essencialy, a white frame with the words "Discussing", "Formalizing", etc. in a rectangle in the right top of the frame, but this rectangle, in each kind of frame shall be in a color (discussing is blue, problems are green, etc.).

I tried to addapt [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173201/beamer-template-with-different-style-options-for-frames/501422#501422) but I was not able to change colors or write in the rectangle :(

Comment: The linked item has been deleted, so there is no useful information there.  Please incorporate the actual content from that link (which was posted by you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following code, I have added an optional argument to `\begin{frame}`. If no argument is given, the resultign slide is just white, if one of the arguments `Discussing`, `Problems` or `Formalizing` is given, the respective word is added in a colored rectangle:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setbeamercolor{mydiscussingcolor}{fg=white,bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{myproblemscolor}{fg=black,bg=green}
\setbeamercolor{myformalizingcolor}{fg=white,bg=red}


\BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{%
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}}


\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{Discussing}[true]{%
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\hfill%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.25\paperwidth,ht=20pt,dp=3ex,center]{mydiscussingcolor}%
  \Large Discussing %
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}}
\define@key{beamerframe}{Problems}[true]{%
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\hfill%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.25\paperwidth,ht=20pt,dp=3ex,center]{myproblemscolor}%
  \Large Problems %
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}}
\define@key{beamerframe}{Formalizing}[true]{%
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\hfill%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.25\paperwidth,ht=20pt,dp=3ex,center]{myformalizingcolor}%
  \Large Formalizing %
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}}
\makeatother




\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[Discussing]
\frametitle{title}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[Problems]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{another title}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[Formalizing]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: PERFECT!!!! Thank you very much!!!