How to add an option to beamer frame?
I have a beamer document
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}

\setlength{\parskip}{\fill}

We have A.

We have B.

\end{frame}

\end{document}

I would like to add an option stretch for a frame, i.e., something like
\begin{frame}[stretch=true]{}

We have A.

We have B.

\end{frame}

With [stretch=true], the command \setlength{\parskip}{\fill} is enabled. Could you elaborate on how to do so?

Update 1: In this question, I want to create a new option for the existing frame environment. In the previous question, I want to create a new frame environment.
Update 2: I have tried
\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{stretch}[true]{%
  \setlength{\parskip}{\fill}
}
\makeatother

but the command \setlength{\parskip}{\fill} is enabled for every frame:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{parskip}

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{stretch}[true]{%
  \setlength{\parskip}{\fill}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[stretch]{Demo}
We have A.

We have B.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Demo}
We have A.

We have B.
\end{frame}

\end{document}


https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/714477/36296 shows how to add a group

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have updated my thread with your solution. Thank you very much.

It is confusing to mix questions and answers. Please don't. user with the same problem will be able to follow the link at the top of your question.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I will move the update part to an answer if my question is open...

An answer isn't necessary, users can follow the link to find the solution. You should simply remove it from the question.
