# combining <+-> and fragile as optional arguments to the begin{frame} command

Tags: beamer, overlays, fragile

I'd like to be able to custom-define a `frame` environment that has two arguments, `<+->` and `fragile`.    The first allows me to uncover items in a list environment, the second allows me to use the matlab-prettifier package.   There seem to be two hurdles
    1) `fragile` seems incompatible with `<+->`
    2) I'm unable to custom-define an environment even just with `fragile` in it.
The MWE below illustrates both problems.    It compiles correctly as written.   There are two commented-out lines.   If you uncomment either of them, and comment out the line below, then `pdflatex` will throw an error   Are there workarounds for either or both problems?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\lstnewenvironment{myMPcolor}{%
            \lstset{basicstyle=\color{red}}
           }{}
%\newenvironment{colorFrame}[fragile][1]{%
\newenvironment{colorFrame}[1]{%
    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=cyan}
      \begin{frame}[<+->]{\hfill #1 \hfill }
    }{\end{frame}}
\begin{document}
%\begin{frame}[<+->,fragile]{Title}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Title}
\begin{itemize}
    \item first point
    \begin{itemize}
        \item subpoint
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\begin{myMPcolor}
This is a matlab command
\end{myMPcolor}
\end{frame}
\begin{colorFrame}{Title}
\begin{itemize}
    \item first point
    \begin{itemize}
        \item subpoint
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{colorFrame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make a complete example that includes what you need a) `<+->` and b) `fragile`? There might be some workaround.

Comment: I've expanded my MWE

Comment: IMHO: trying to use a new environment to wrap around frames in a not a good idea - especially not if you deal with fragile frames, as they explicitly scan the code for `\end{frame}`. However this is another question.

Comment: Instead of a new environment, I suggest the use of frame options to change the background colour, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/395429/36296

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a frame option, you could directly pass `<+->` to the itemize environments:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\lstnewenvironment{myMPcolor}{%
            \lstset{basicstyle=\color{red}}
           }{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Title}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item first point
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item subpoint
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\begin{myMPcolor}
This is a matlab command
\end{myMPcolor}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

If you need a more automatic solution, you could also use

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\lstnewenvironment{myMPcolor}{%
            \lstset{basicstyle=\color{red}}
           }{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Title}
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
\begin{itemize}
    \item first point
    \begin{itemize}
        \item subpoint
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\begin{myMPcolor}
This is a matlab command
\end{myMPcolor}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually I wanted something slightly more and have posed it as a new question here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422868/creating-a-beginframefragile-macro