# Creating a begin{frame}[fragile] macro

Tags: beamer, environments, fragile

This is a follow up to my question in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/421798/combining-and-fragile-as-optional-arguments-to-the-beginframe-command?noredirect=1#comment1054525_421798), in response to which @samcarter showed me how to combine `<+->` with `fragile`.      In the example below, I've tried to further automate his code by creating a `fragileFrame` environment which includes both of the above features.  (Obviously, in this MWE it doesn't gain me much, but in my actual code, my beamer frames contain a lot of customization, which I don't want to have rewrite every time.   However the environment construction throws an error.   To verify that it really is the `fragile` option that's causing the error, I've created a `normalFrame` environment that is identical except for the `fragile` option, and compiles without error.    Is there a way to get around this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\lstnewenvironment{myMPcolor}{%
            \lstset{basicstyle=\color{red}}
           }{}
\newenvironment{fragileFrame}[1]{%
    \beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
      \begin{frame}[fragile]{#1}
    }{\end{frame}}
\newenvironment{normalFrame}[1]{%
    \beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
      \begin{frame}{#1}
    }{\end{frame}}
\begin{document}
\begin{normalFrame}{Title}
\begin{itemize}
    \item first point
    \begin{itemize}
        \item subpoint
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{normalFrame}
\begin{fragileFrame}{Title}
\begin{itemize}
    \item first point
    \begin{itemize}
        \item subpoint
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\begin{myMPcolor}
This is a matlab command
\end{myMPcolor}
\end{fragileFrame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

As said in a comment to your previous question, hiding the frame environment in a new environment is a bad idea - this usually causes more problems than it solves.

However if you really must do it:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\lstnewenvironment{myMPcolor}{%
            \lstset{basicstyle=\color{red}}
           }{}

\newenvironment{slide}
    {\begin{frame}[fragile,environment=slide]}
    {\end{frame}}

\begin{document}

\begin{slide}
\frametitle{title}
\begin{itemize}
    \item first point
    \begin{itemize}
        \item subpoint
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\begin{myMPcolor}
This is a matlab command
\end{myMPcolor}
\end{slide} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Cool.   Thanks very much.      I'll take my chances on hiding frames inside new environments.  I've been doing it without problems----until this one---for years.