# How to put a black background and white letters in a poster?

Tags: beamerposter, posters

I'm using a Jacobs Landscape Poster.

While I'm working on the poster, I would like to transform the white background into black, and the black letters into white.

In a normal tex document, I would use

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xcolor}%Comment out before printing
\pagecolor[rgb]{0,0,0}%Comment out before printing
\color[rgb]{1,1,1}%Comment out before printing
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

I've tried that, but it doesn't work properly with the poster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jacobs Landscape Poster is implemented as a `beamer` presentation with only one very large frame. Therefore, you can use the regular color settings of `beamer` for the background and the blocks, see for example [Change the background color of a frame in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8043/change-the-background-color-of-a-frame-in-beamer) and other questions linked from there.

Example code fragment, using the template from https://www.latextemplates.com/template/jacobs-landscape-poster:

```
\title{\color{white}Unnecessarily Complicated Research Title} % Poster title
\author{John Smith, James Smith and Jane Smith} % Author(s)
\institute{Department and University Name} % Institution(s)

\begin{document}

\addtobeamertemplate{block end}{}{\vspace*{2ex}} % White space under blocks
\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted end}{}{\vspace*{2ex}} % White space under highlighted (alert) blocks

\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{2ex} % White space under figures
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{2ex} % White space under equations
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=black} 
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=white,bg=black} % Colors of the body of blocks
\setbeamercolor{block alerted body}{fg=white,bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{title in headline}{fg=white,bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{author in headline}{fg=white,bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{institution in headline}{fg=white,bg=black}
\begin{frame}[t] % The whole poster is enclosed in one beamer frame
```

Result:

[image]

Note that the color for the title is explicitly set to white within the title itself, because the template has a hardcoded blue color for the title that is set just before the title is inserted (`\usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\color{jblue}\Huge{\textbf{\inserttitle}}\\[0.5ex]}` in `beamerthemeconfposter.sty`).