# Beamer frame option to change background and font that works with labels

Tags: beamer, key-value

I'd like to define a frame option in Beamer to "invert" the colors of background, foreground, and structure, and I can do so by defining

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{%
  \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black, bg=white}%
  \setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=blue}%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}%
}

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{bg}[true]{%
  \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white, bg=black}%
  \setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=red}%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Normal}
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}[bg]
    \frametitle{Inverted}
    A statement
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which results in
[image: success?]

However, assigning the frame a label

```latex
\begin{frame}[bg, label=test]
  \frametitle{Inverted}
  A statement
\end{frame}
```

results in the error

```
Package keyval Error: label undefined \end{frame}
```

Now this is already a problem, but we could say only a minor problem, since it can be circumvented by placing the label first.

Things really start to spiral out of my control when I'd like to reuse the frame

```latex
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}<1>[label=test, bg]
    \frametitle{Inverted}
    \only<1>{A statement}
    \only<2>{Another statement}
    \only<3>{Third statement}
  \end{frame}

  \againframe<2>{test}

  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Normal}
  \end{frame}

  \againframe<3>{test}
\end{document}
```

[image: failure]
Somehow the frame option affects all contiguous frames, but not if there's a "normal" frame in-between.

The behaviour I was expecting to see, is that the inversion would *not* affect the repeated frames, but instead the frame option would need to be passed again. However, doing that

```latex
\againframe<3>[bg]{test}
```

results in the error

```
Package keyval Error: relabel undefined
```

If changing only the frame background following the example of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/395429/199342, the label order issue disappears, as does the issue of not being able to pass the option to `\againframe`. Nevertheless, the frame option still affects contiguous frames even without passing the option, but passing it does not result in any errors either.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\defbeamertemplate*{background canvas}{mydefault}{%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{background canvas}{}{\color{bg}\vrule width\paperwidth height\paperheight}%
}

\defbeamertemplate*{background canvas}{bg}{%
  \color{black}\vrule width\paperwidth height\paperheight%
}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{%
  \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[mydefault]%
}
\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{bg}[true]{%
  \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[bg]%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}<1>[bg, label=test]
    \frametitle{Inverted}
    \only<1>{First point}
    \only<2>{Second point}
    \only<3>{Third point}
  \end{frame}

  \againframe<2>{test}

  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Normal}
  \end{frame}

  \againframe<3>[bg]{test}
\end{document}
```

[image: background]

But I'd really like the frame option to change the font colors as well. Is there some way to achieve the functionality I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the same as in [noframenumbering in Metropolis' standout frames](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/609581) you're nesting `\setkeys` calls which aren't nestable. As a result the `label` key isn't parsed as part of the optional argument of `frame` but as part of the set used for `\setbeamercolor`.

Incidentally that question also contains a fix for your color-leakage problem. You try to revert the colours using `\BeforeBeginEnvironment`, but the `frame` environment isn't used by `\againframe` so your resetting code isn't executed. The fix would be to revert the colours at the end of the frame `bg` is applied to (by scoping it using `\begingroup`...`\endgroup` with a conditional to keep track of it).

The following patches `\setkeys` to be nestable and implements the fix for your colour settings.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
% patch \setkeys to be nestable:
\NewCommandCopy\my@setkeys@orig\setkeys
\def\setkeys{\expandafter\my@setkeys@aux\expandafter{\KV@prefix}}
\long\def\my@setkeys@aux#1#2#3{\my@setkeys@orig{#2}{#3}\def\KV@prefix{#1}}


\newif\ifbgframe
\define@key{beamerframe}{bg}[true]{%
  \bgframetrue
  \begingroup
  \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white, bg=black}%
  \setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=red}%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}%
}
\pretocmd{\beamer@reseteecodes}{%
  \ifbgframe
    \endgroup
    \bgframefalse
  \fi
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}<1>[bg, label=test]
    \frametitle{Inverted}
    \only<1>{A statement}
    \only<2>{Another statement}
    \only<3>{Third statement}
  \end{frame}

  \againframe<2>{test}

  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Normal}
  \end{frame}

  \againframe<3>{test}
\end{document}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Normal}
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}[bg]
    \frametitle{Inverted}
    A statement
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I changed `\NewCommandCopy` to `\let` to support older LaTeX versions.