# noframenumbering in Metropolis' standout frames

Tags: beamer, key-value, beamer-metropolis

I would like to make it optional to exclude the standout frames from the beamer theme Metropolis from the frame count. This works as long as I write my frame options as `noframenumbering, standout`. But if I reverse the order and write `standout, noframenumbering` then I get an error

```
Package keyval Error: noframenumbering undefined. [  \end{frame}]
```

in my MWE (below). What should I do to allow both orders?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% Standout frame code from [Metropolis' inner theme](https://github.com/matze/mtheme/blob/master/source/beamerinnerthememetropolis.dtx)
\usepackage{keyval}
\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{c}[true]{% centered
  \beamer@frametopskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
  \beamer@frametopskipautobreak=0pt plus .4\paperheight\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=0pt plus .6\paperheight\relax%
  \def\beamer@initfirstlineunskip{}%
}
\providebool{metropolis@standout}
\define@key{beamerframe}{standout}[true]{%
  \booltrue{metropolis@standout}
  \begingroup
    \setkeys{beamerframe}{c}
    \setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}{}
    % \setkeys{beamerframe}{noframenumbering}
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{palette primary}{
      \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{
        use=palette primary,
        bg=-palette primary.fg
      }
    }{
      \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{
        use=palette primary,
        bg=palette primary.bg
      }
    }
  \centering
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{palette primary}
  \usebeamerfont{standout}
}
\pretocmd{\beamer@reseteecodes}{%
  \ifbool{metropolis@standout}{
    \endgroup
    \boolfalse{metropolis@standout}
  }{}
}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[standout]
    standout
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}[noframenumbering, standout]
    noframenumbering, standout
  \end{frame}

  % This frame produces the error message
  \begin{frame}[standout, noframenumbering]
    standout, noframenumbering
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you need to this in the first place? It is normal that some keys aren't commutative. And do you really want to change the definitions of the `metropolis` theme?

Comment: @Skillmon I'm working on a stripped down version on Metropolis without a lot of the bells and whistles. I like the standout frames and would like to include them in the frame count. That is, unless the frame options contain `noframenumbering`. And I would prefer not having to think about which order I enter the options.

Comment: This turns out to be really weird. The lines creating this problem are the `\setbeamercolor{background canvas}` instructions inside the `standout` code. But they don't immediately undefine the `noframenumbering` key (directly afterwards the key still exists), and the key also exists inside a `frame` environment which uses the `standout` option. Furthermore, it doesn't depend on the colour you change (e.g., use `\setbeamercolor{something unrelated}` instead), and even if nothing is changed (empty second argument) the error shows up. This looks like a strange `beamer` bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This answer was only possible due to the kind help of [@samcarter](https://topanswers.xyz/transcript?room=347&id=116142#c116142)!**

The issue is that `\setbeamercolor` uses `\setkeys` internally, and `keyval`'s `\setkeys` can't be nested, if you nest them the key prefix of the inner call is used for the remainder of the outer call, so `noframenumbering` isn't parsed as part of `beamerframe`, but `beamerthc` (which is used internally by `\setbeamercolor`).

To fix this you have two fundamentally different approaches:

1. Don't use `\setbeamercolor` but the internals this would call directly. (approach taken by @samcarter, could theoretically break if `beamer` changed its own internals)
2. Fix `\setkeys` to be nestable. (general fix for `keyval`, shouldn't have evil side effects, but theoretically could if some code relies on this limitation of `\setkeys`)

### Using internals of `\setbeamercolor`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% Standout frame code from [Metropolis' inner theme](https://github.com/matze/mtheme/blob/master/source/beamerinnerthememetropolis.dtx)
%\usepackage{keyval}
\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{c}[true]{% centered
  \beamer@frametopskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
  \beamer@frametopskipautobreak=0pt plus .4\paperheight\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=0pt plus .6\paperheight\relax%
  \def\beamer@initfirstlineunskip{}%
}
\providebool{metropolis@standout}
\define@key{beamerframe}{standout}[true]{%
  \booltrue{metropolis@standout}%
  \begingroup
    \setkeys{beamerframe}{c}%
    \setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}{}%
    % \setkeys{beamerframe}{noframenumbering}%
    \def\beamer@temp{background canvas}%
    \expandafter\def\csname beamer@thcuse@\beamer@temp\endcsname{%
        \@for\@temp:={palette primary}\do{\expandafter\beamer@thc@usecolor\expandafter{\@temp}}}%
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{palette primary}{%
       \expandafter\def\csname beamer@thcbg@\beamer@temp\endcsname{\def\beamer@thc@bg{-palette primary.fg}}%
    }{%
       \expandafter\def\csname beamer@thcbg@\beamer@temp\endcsname{\def\beamer@thc@bg{palette primary.bg}}%
    }%
  \centering
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{palette primary}%
  \usebeamerfont{standout}%
}
\pretocmd{\beamer@reseteecodes}{%
  \ifbool{metropolis@standout}{%
    \endgroup
    \boolfalse{metropolis@standout}%
  }{}%
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[standout]
    standout
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}[noframenumbering, standout]
    noframenumbering, standout
  \end{frame}

  % This frame produces the error message
  \begin{frame}[standout, noframenumbering]
    standout, noframenumbering
  \end{frame}
  
  \begin{frame}
  content...
  \insertframenumber
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Patching `\setkeys`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% Standout frame code from [Metropolis' inner theme](https://github.com/matze/mtheme/blob/master/source/beamerinnerthememetropolis.dtx)
%\usepackage{keyval} % loaded by beamer

\makeatletter
% patch \setkeys to be nestable:
\NewCommandCopy\my@setkeys@orig\setkeys
\def\setkeys{\expandafter\my@setkeys@aux\expandafter{\KV@prefix}}
\long\def\my@setkeys@aux#1#2#3{\my@setkeys@orig{#2}{#3}\def\KV@prefix{#1}}

\define@key{beamerframe}{c}[true]{% centered
  \beamer@frametopskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax
  \beamer@framebottomskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax
  \beamer@frametopskipautobreak=0pt plus .4\paperheight\relax
  \beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=0pt plus .6\paperheight\relax
  \def\beamer@initfirstlineunskip{}%
}
\providebool{metropolis@standout}
\let\KV@beamerframe@cx\KV@beamerframe@c
\let\KV@beamerframe@cx@default\KV@beamerframe@c@default
\define@key{beamerframe}{standout}[true]{%
  \booltrue{metropolis@standout}%
  \begingroup
    \setkeys{beamerframe}{cx}%
    \setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}{}%
    % \setkeys{beamerframe}{noframenumbering}%
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{palette primary}{%
      \setbeamercolor{unrelated beamer color}{%
        use=palette primary,
        bg=-palette primary.fg
      }%
    }{%
      \setbeamercolor{unrelated beamer color}{%
        use=palette primary,
        bg=palette primary.bg
      }%
    }%
  \centering
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{palette primary}%
  \usebeamerfont{standout}%
}
\pretocmd{\beamer@reseteecodes}{%
  \ifbool{metropolis@standout}{%
    \endgroup
    \boolfalse{metropolis@standout}%
  }{}%
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}[standout]
    standout
  \end{frame}

  \makeatletter
  \begin{frame}[noframenumbering, standout]
    noframenumbering, standout
  \end{frame}

  % This frame produces the error message
  \begin{frame}[standout, noframenumbering]
      %\show\KV@beamerframe@noframenumbering
    standout, noframenumbering
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}
    normal
    \insertframenumber
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```