# Beamer: How to set background color only on title page in theme

Tags: beamer, color, backgrounds, themes

I'm developing a Beamer theme and I want to make the background color of the title page one color and all the other slides to have a different color.

I've [found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8045/6324) that I can change the background color for a slide using:

```latex
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=violet}
```

I want to do this in the beamer theme style file, not in the latex document and I couldn't figure out how to do that.

---

I know I can change the background color on slide 1 like this:

```tex
\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
    \ifnum\c@framenumber=1%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={fill=blue}, show background rectangle]
            \hspace*{20em}
            \node[opacity=0.45, scale=5.6]{\includegraphics{background}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \else%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={fill=white}, show background rectangle]
            \hspace*{20em}
            \node[opacity=0.09, scale=5.6]{\includegraphics{background}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \fi%
```

This works if the title slide is the first slide---almost always the case. It does not work if putting multiple title slides in the same file, which I do on occasion.

---

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish. In this example, I'm using the excellent Metropolis theme. This example shows that I can have two different title slides in the same presentation. It does *not* show that there is a different background color in the title slide. Of course, I want to implement this in my own theme. (I'm sorry that I can't share all of my style file.)

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}

\begin{document}
\title{First Title}
\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Some title}
  Some content here
\end{frame}

\title{Second Title}
\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE1]
[image: MWE2]
[image: MWE3]

Comment: Can you provide a basic minimal document, say one with a single title slide, and one with multiple slides (or non-first-slide) so the community can work with that information?

Comment: @Werner I've uploaded an example of using two title slides in the same presentation. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a `tikzpicture` to the `title page` template that draws the background directly use the coordinates of the `current page`:

[image: Sample output]

### `beamerthememytheme.sty`

```
\usetheme{metropolis}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\addtobeamertemplate{title page}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \draw[fill=violet!20!white] (current page.south west) rectangle
  (current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}{}
```

### main file

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{mytheme}

\begin{document}
\title{First Title}
\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Some title}
  Some content here
\end{frame}

\title{Second Title}
\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

`\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=violet}` actually works, but I haven't found a way to use it in `setbeamertemplate`.

It can be used it document between frames to change their background as such:

```
\begin{document}

% Switch to custom background color for title frame
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=violet}

\title{First Title}
\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}

% Set back the background color for other frames.
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}

\begin{frame}{Some title}
  Some content here
\end{frame}

\title{Second Title}
\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```